# Keyboard not resigning in IOS 7

Tags: ios, resignfirstresponder

I use a UIText field as a toggle to display and then update with a value each time it is depressed, and use the the didbeginediting as the action to resign the keyboard.  In 6.2 this works fine in 7 the keyboard is not resigned.

```
-(void)toggleAnswer {

self.myText resignfirstresponder;
if ([myText.text isEqualTo @"Yes"]) {
    myText.text = @"No";
   }
else {
    myText.text = @"No";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be because I'm using a custom keyboard, but calling

```
[myUITextField resignFirstResponder];
```

stopped removing my keyboard under iOS7, despite having worked fine under iOS6.  However, what I found works great under both iOS6 and iOS7 is calling

```
[myUIViewController.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: For me, under iOS7, this causes isFirstResponder to return NO, but the keyboard doesn't get dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

Take three Step in count

1) set delegate for textfield `<UITextFieldDelegate>`

2) set Delegate for particular textfielf `yourtextfielg.delegate=self`.

3) Resign that particular textField `[txt resignFirstResponder]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this


 if(textField == textFieldname1)
    {
        [textFieldname2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if(textField == textFieldname2)
    {
        [textFieldname3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else
    {

            // Not found, so remove keyboard.
            [textField resignFirstResponder];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 @interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

// set this somewhere

 yourTextField.delegate = self;
```